Unable to Use tf.image.rot90
I am working on a semantic segmantation problem, where x is of shape (batch_size,1,256,256) and y ( mask) is of shape (batch_size,2,256,256), where 2 is the number of classes and i am working with channels_first format. I want to add rotation mechanism to my data augmentation part in my data pipeline using:
# Data Augmentation 
def augment_image(image,mask1):
        
    # Flip and rotate the image and mask 50% of the time
    if tf.random.uniform(()) > 0.5:

        image = tf.image.flip_left_right(image)
        mask = tf.image.flip_left_right(mask)

    if tf.random.uniform(()) > 0.5:
  
        image = tf.image.flip_up_down(image)
        mask = tf.image.flip_up_down(mask)

    if tf.random.uniform(()) > 0.5:
        # Rotate the image and mask using tf.image.rot90
        image = tf.image.rot90(image,k = 2)
        mask = tf.image.rot90(mask, k = 2)

    return image, mask

When I start training the model I get :
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnknownError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-e16e198b1602> in <cell line: 9>()
     90     # Train the model
     91 
---> 92     history = model.fit(x = train_dataset,
     93                         batch_size= batch_size,
     94                         steps_per_epoch= steps_per_epoch,

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
    120             # To get the full stack trace, call:
    121             # `keras.config.disable_traceback_filtering()`
--> 122             raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    123         finally:
    124             del filtered_tb

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     51   try:
     52     ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 53     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
     54                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     55   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:

UnknownError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node PyFunc defined at (most recent call last):
<stack traces unavailable>
Detected at node PyFunc defined at (most recent call last):
<stack traces unavailable>
2 root error(s) found.
  (0) UNKNOWN:  Error in user-defined function passed to ParallelMapDatasetV2:30 transformation with iterator: Iterator::Root::Prefetch::BatchV2::FiniteRepeat[0]::ParallelMapV2: InvalidArgumentError: Expected 'tf.Tensor(False, shape=(), dtype=bool)' to be true. Summarized data: b'Input error: exclusive=True: more than 1 conditions (?, ?, ?) evaluated as True:'
False, True, True
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/script_ops.py", line 270, in __call__
    ret = func(*args)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py", line 643, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/tmp/__autograph_generated_filekah454m5.py", line 61, in f
    ag__.if_stmt(ag__.ld(data_augmentation), if_body_1, else_body_1, get_state_1, set_state_1, ('x', 'y'), 2)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/operators/control_flow.py", line 1217, in if_stmt
    _py_if_stmt(cond, body, orelse)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/operators/control_flow.py", line 1270, in _py_if_stmt
    return body() if cond else orelse()

  File "/tmp/__autograph_generated_filekah454m5.py", line 54, in if_body_1
    (x, y) = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(augment_image), (ag__.ld(x), ag__.ld(y)), None, fscope_1)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py", line 335, in converted_call
    return _call_unconverted(f, args, kwargs, options, False)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py", line 460, in _call_unconverted
    return f(*args)

  File "<ipython-input-7-d7c47bcda2ed>", line 85, in augment_image
    image = tf.image.rot90(image,k = 2)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/traceback_utils.py", line 153, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_assert.py", line 102, in Assert
    raise errors.InvalidArgumentError(

tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Expected 'tf.Tensor(False, shape=(), dtype=bool)' to be true. Summarized data: b'Input error: exclusive=True: more than 1 conditions (?, ?, ?) evaluated as True:'
False, True, True


     [[{{node PyFunc}}]]
     [[IteratorGetNext]]
     [[IteratorGetNext/_2]]
  (1) UNKNOWN:  Error in user-defined function passed to ParallelMapDatasetV2:30 transformation with iterator: Iterator::Root::Prefetch::BatchV2::FiniteRepeat[0]::ParallelMapV2: InvalidArgumentError: Expected 'tf.Tensor(False, shape=(), dtype=bool)' to be true. Summarized data: b'Input error: exclusive=True: more than 1 conditions (?, ?, ?) evaluated as True:'
False, True, True
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/script_ops.py", line 270, in __call__
    ret = func(*args)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py", line 643, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/tmp/__autograph_generated_filekah454m5.py", line 61, in f
    ag__.if_stmt(ag__.ld(data_augmentation), if_body_1, else_body_1, get_state_1, set_state_1, ('x', 'y'), 2)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/operators/control_flow.py", line 1217, in if_stmt
    _py_if_stmt(cond, body, orelse)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/operators/control_flow.py", line 1270, in _py_if_stmt
    return body() if cond else orelse()

  File "/tmp/__autograph_generated_filekah454m5.py", line 54, in if_body_1
    (x, y) = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(augment_image), (ag__.ld(x), ag__.ld(y)), None, fscope_1)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py", line 335, in converted_call
    return _call_unconverted(f, args, kwargs, options, False)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py", line 460, in _call_unconverted
    return f(*args)

  File "<ipython-input-7-d7c47bcda2ed>", line 85, in augment_image
    image = tf.image.rot90(image,k = 2)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/traceback_utils.py", line 153, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_assert.py", line 102, in Assert
    raise errors.InvalidArgumentError(

tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Expected 'tf.Tensor(False, shape=(), dtype=bool)' to be true. Summarized data: b'Input error: exclusive=True: more than 1 conditions (?, ?, ?) evaluated as True:'
False, True, True


     [[{{node PyFunc}}]]
     [[IteratorGetNext]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored. [Op:__inference_one_step_on_iterator_44075]

Even I tried to pass k as a random tensor using :
    # Generate a random integer k (1, 2, or 3) corresponding to 90, 180, or 270 degrees
    k = tf.random.uniform([], minval=1, maxval=4, dtype=tf.int32)

Still I get an error. The problem ordinates from this rotating function as when I remove it everything works fine.  I am running the model on kaggle where :
print("TensorFlow version:", tf.__version__)

TensorFlow version: 2.17.0

Here is the data pipeline:
# Image Standardization
def standardize_image(x):
    """
    Standardizes the image by subtracting the mean and dividing by the standard deviation for each channel.
    The image should have shape (H, W, C), where H is height, W is width, and C is the number of channels (3 for RGB).
    """
    # Calculate the mean and std for each channel
    mean = tf.reduce_mean(x, axis=(0, 1), keepdims=True)
    std = tf.math.reduce_std(x, axis=(0, 1), keepdims=True)

    # Standardize the image: (x - mean) / (std + epsilon) to avoid division by zero
    epsilon = 1e-7  # A small constant to avoid division by zero
    standardized_image = (x - mean) / (std + epsilon)

    return standardized_image


# Function to read the input image
def read_image(image_path):
    try:
        x = tf.io.read_file(image_path)         # Read the file as a string
        x = tf.image.decode_jpeg(x, channels=3) # Decode the JPEG file into a 3-channel RGB image
        x = tf.cast(x, tf.float32) / 255.0      # Normalize pixel values to the range [0, 1]
        """        if tf.shape(x)[0] != 512 or tf.shape(x)[1] != 512 or tf.shape(x)[2] != 3:
            raise ValueError(f"Invalid image dimensions: {tf.shape(x).numpy()}, expected (512, 512, 3)")"""

        x = tf.image.resize(x, [img_size, img_size], method=tf.image.ResizeMethod.AREA , preserve_aspect_ratio = True)


        # Add channel dimension as the first dimension
        #x = np.transpose(x, (2, 0, 1))
        return x
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error reading image: {image_path}, Error: {e}")
        return None

# Function to read the mask image
def read_mask(mask_path):
    try:

        
        # Load the mask directly as a .npy file using numpy
        y = np.load(mask_path)

        # Convert the loaded numpy array to a TensorFlow tensor
        y = tf.convert_to_tensor(y, dtype=tf.float32)
        
        # Ensure the mask has the correct shape (512, 512, 2)
        y.set_shape((512, 512, 2))  # Set shape for the mask tensor

        # Resize the mask to match the image size (img_size, img_size, 2)
        y = tf.image.resize(y, [img_size, img_size], method=tf.image.ResizeMethod.NEAREST_NEIGHBOR, preserve_aspect_ratio = True)

        # Convert the mask to channel-first format (2, img_size, img_size)
        y = tf.transpose(y, perm=[2, 0, 1])  # [H, W, C] -> [C, H, W]
        return y
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error reading mask: {mask_path}, Error: {e}")
        return None



# Data Augmentation 
def augment_image(image,mask1):
        
    # Flip and rotate the image and mask 50% of the time
    if tf.random.uniform(()) > 0.5:

        image = tf.image.flip_left_right(image)
        mask = tf.image.flip_left_right(mask1)
        

    if tf.random.uniform(()) > 0.5:
  
        image = tf.image.flip_up_down(image)
        mask = tf.image.flip_up_down(mask1)
      
       

    if tf.random.uniform(()) > 0.5:


        # Rotate the image and mask using tf.image.rot90
        image = tf.image.rot90(image,k = 2)
        mask = tf.image.rot90(mask1, k = 2)
       
    
    
    
    return image, mask
    
# Preprocessing function
def preprocess(x, y, data_augmentation = False):
    def f(x, y):
        x = x.decode()
        y = y.decode()
        x = read_image(x)
        y = read_mask(y)
        # convert the input image to grayscale
        x = tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale(x)
        # Standardize each channel of the input image
        x= standardize_image(x)
        # Add channel dimension as the first dimension
        x = tf.transpose(x, perm=[2, 0, 1])




        
        # Apply data augmentation
    
        if data_augmentation:

            x = tf.transpose(x, perm=[1, 2, 0])  # [C, H, W] -> [H, W, C]
            y = tf.transpose(y, perm=[1, 2, 0])  # [C, H, W] -> [H, W, C]
      
            x,y = augment_image(x,y)

            # Convert back to channels_first format using NumPy
            x = np.transpose(x, (2, 0, 1))  # [H, W, C] -> [C, H, W]
            y = np.transpose(y, (2, 0, 1))  # [H, W, C] -> [C, H, W]

        
        '''        # Check if x or y is None
        if x is None or y is None:
            print(f"Error: One of the inputs is None for {x}, {y}")
            raise ValueError("One of the inputs is None")
        
        # Check if x has NaN or Inf values
        if tf.reduce_any(tf.is_nan(x)) or tf.reduce_any(tf.is_inf(x)):
            raise ValueError("NaN or Inf found in image data")
        
        # Check if y has NaN or Inf values
        if tf.reduce_any(tf.is_nan(y)) or tf.reduce_any(tf.is_inf(y)):
            raise ValueError("NaN or Inf found in mask data")'''

        return x, y
    # Integrate a custom Python function (f) into the TensorFlow graph.
    x, y = tf.numpy_function(f, [x, y], [tf.float32, tf.float32])
    x.set_shape((1,img_size, img_size))
    y.set_shape((2,img_size, img_size))

    return x, y

# Create the TensorFlow dataset
def tf_dataset(x, y, batch_size=32, epochs=30, data_augmentation = False):
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x, y))
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=100)
    dataset = dataset.map(lambda a, b: preprocess(a, b, data_augmentation), num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
    dataset = dataset.repeat(epochs).batch(batch_size)
    dataset = dataset.prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
    return dataset

x and y are paths to the image files

I can run a array like (3, 224, 224) or (2, 224, 224) with tf.image.rot90 (tf 2.17), it works, no issue. I think the problem in your dataloader. Please provide reproducible code.

@Innat I have added the code for the data pipeline. Thanks a lot.

You are using tf.data API and use numpy with it. That's maybe the aroot cause. If you rrally need to use np here, use tf.py_function. However its better to use tensorflow as far as possible.

@Innat Thank you so much for your reply ! I am confused as I am already using x, y = tf.numpy_function(f, [x, y], [tf.float32, tf.float32]). So I dont know what to do more.

I see. Why not using without needing such wrapper? I think keras has rotation layer that can be used as augmentation.

@Innat yes you are correct. But, I just want to rotate with rotation angles that are multiple of 90 degrees ( 90,180,270) to avoid clipping any regions as my image is a square image. The rotation layer provided by keras takes a range of angles , where it randomly selects an angle in that range. So, its not guaranteed to achieve what I want.

Okay. One possible solution, how about adding you all augmentation layers inside de the model. Those will only activists with model.fit and deactivate with inference api.

@Innat if that is possible then it will be a good solution to try. But how can I do that especially for the rotation ? Also I converted the operations in my data pipeline to follow  tensorflow , except for np.load for loading the mask as its type is .npy. i will add the new pipeline in the question, but still I am getting the same error.

I can provide a minimal starter. Before that, can you adopt your pipeline based on this soluton. Look at only the data loading pipeline. Hopefully .npy can be saved in image file at first.

Also, if you can provide some data sample (dummy) similar to yours, that would be nice.
